# How do I add % "Adopted" over each bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
pet_bar <- ggplot(pet_adopt, aes(x=Size, group = Status)) +  
  geom_bar(width= 0.65, aes(fill= Status)) + 
  geom_text(stat="count", position = position_stack(vjust= 0.5), aes(fill=Size,label = ..count..)) + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.93, 0.88), axis.title = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "gray"), axis.ticks = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()) + 
  facet_grid(~gender) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray60", "gray90")) + 
  ggtitle("Adoption Status of Dogs during the Summer of 2020")

pet_bar
```

[image]

Comment: Is it a label you are looking to add to each bar?

Comment: yes. a % adopted for each bar

Answer (score 2):

Some fake data, so I can reproduce your plotting code:

```
fake_pet_adopt = crossing(gender = c("Female", "Male"),
                          Status = c("Adopted", "Not Adopted"),
                          Size = c("Large", "Medium", "Small")) %>%
  mutate(number = 32:21) %>%
  uncount(number)
```

Edit: I misread the original question before, and have updated here to have the text over the bars represent "% adopted" not total #. There are a few calculations, so I find it simpler to do those before ggplot using `dplyr` functions:

```
fake_pet_adopt_counts <- fake_pet_adopt %>%
  count(gender, Size, Status)

adopt_shares <- fake_pet_adopt_counts %>%
  group_by(gender, Size) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(n),
         share = n / sum(n)) %>%
  filter(Status == "Adopted")
```

Then we can feed those in, where one text layer uses the `adopt_shares` table to get the % labels and locations:

```
ggplot(fake_pet_adopt_counts, 
       aes(x=Size, y = n, label = n, group = Status)) +  
  geom_col(width= 0.65, aes(fill= Status)) +
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust= 0.5)) +
  geom_text(data = adopt_shares, vjust = -0.2,
            aes(y = total, label = scales::percent(share, accuracy = 0.1))) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.93, 0.88), axis.title = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "gray"), axis.ticks = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()) + 
  facet_grid(~gender)  +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray60", "gray90")) + 
  ggtitle("Adoption Status of Dogs during the Summer of 2020")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how to turn the bar totals into percent "Adopted"? So for Female Large it would be 32/61 for 52.4%

Comment: Edited to correct my misreading of the question.